# Bigquery job failed with error: Encountered " "FROM" "FROM ""

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm calling a SQL query with a BigQuery API with Airflow. This query works perfectly fine in the BigQuery workspace but says I'm writing `FROM FROM` even though I'm not...

The logs say line 4, character 20 is where the error occurs which corresponds to:

`, EXTRACT(DATE FROM event_time) AS session_date`.

My overall query structure looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
((SELECT
     fields_here
     FROM table_name
     LEFT JOIN UNNEST(sub_table) AS s 
     WHERE 1=1
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT
     fields_here
     FROM table_name
     LEFT JOIN UNNEST(sub_table) AS s 
     WHERE 1=1
     ORDER BY 1, 2))
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I'm also using the `LEAD()` window function and `COALESCE()` but not sure if that matters. Really confused why this error is occurring...

Comment: Hi @RicardoFrancois, Can you provide your sample data and expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's relevant here because this query works fine in BigQuery still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not adding `use_legacy_sql=False` argument in Airflow